# boto3 client.list_topics() doesn't give me error information

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, boto3

I have a lambda function in python give administrator access.

the code in lambda function is

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
client = boto3.client('sns')
try:
    client.list_topics()
except Exception, err:
    print Exception, err
```

trying to reach sns topics.

but when I save and test, I can only see the following message:

```
{
"errorMessage": "2016-07-01T13:51:22.194Z e2605d0d-3f92-11e6-a117-  fb73aa4f9916 Task timed out after 4.00 seconds"
}
```

why my print sentence doesn't print the error message for me, what could go wrong in this case

Comment: Your function is timing out. Did you perhaps enable VPC access for the Lambda function without adding a NAT gateway to the VPC?

Comment: @MarkB  you are right. that is the reason

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it looks like your Lambda function is timing out before the API call can finish.  Try increasing your Lambda function's `timeout` value and try again.